# tags$style specific modaldialog element in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tags, modal-dialog

basic syntax question I think, but i'm stuck on it. 
I have an app with many elements that I try to style, for instance modalDialogs. 
How do I make this code specific to only modaldialog 1, and not apply to modaldialog 2?

```
tags$head(tags$style(".modal-body {padding: 10px}
                     .modal-content  {-webkit-border-radius: 6px !important;-moz-border-radius: 6px !important;border-radius: 6px !important;}
                     .modal-dialog { width: 240px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}
                     .modal-header {background-color: #339FFF; border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px}
                     .modal { text-align: right; padding-right:10px; padding-top: 24px;}
                     .close { font-size: 16px}"))
```

full demo app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  tags$head(tags$style(".modal-body {padding: 10px}
                         .modal-content  {-webkit-border-radius: 6px !important;-moz-border-radius: 6px !important;border-radius: 6px !important;}
                       .modal-dialog { width: 240px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}
                       .modal-header {background-color: #339FFF; border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px}
                       .modal { text-align: right; padding-right:10px; padding-top: 24px;}
                       .close { font-size: 16px}")),
  h5("Hello there"),                                          # First text on the window
  br(),                                                       # empty line
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe", label = "button1"),   # button 1
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe2", label = "button2") # button 2
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      inputId = 'Dialog1', 
      title = HTML('<span style="color:white; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Display help popups<span>
                   <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                   <span style="color:white; ">x <span>
                   </button> '),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe2,{

    showModal(modalDialog(
      inputId = 'Dialog2', 
      title = HTML('<span style="color:white; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Display help popups<span>
                   <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                   <span style="color:white; ">x <span>
                   </button> '),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL ))
      })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

thanks for helping if you can!

Mark

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A possiblity: enclose the modal inside a div container with an id (e.g. `modal1`):

```
showModal(tags$div(id="modal1", modalDialog(
  inputId = 'Dialog1', 
  title = HTML('<span style="color:white; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Display help popups<span>
               <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
               <span style="color:white; ">x <span>
               </button> '),
  easyClose = TRUE,
  footer = NULL )))
```

and then use this css:

```
  tags$head(tags$style("#modal1 .modal-body {padding: 10px}
                       #modal1 .modal-content  {-webkit-border-radius: 6px !important;-moz-border-radius: 6px !important;border-radius: 6px !important;}
                       #modal1 .modal-dialog { width: 240px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}
                       #modal1 .modal-header {background-color: #339FFF; border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px}
                       #modal1 .modal { text-align: right; padding-right:10px; padding-top: 24px;}
                       #modal1 .close { font-size: 16px}"))
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to add #Dialog1 everywhere you put #modal1, wasn't sure why that fails  p.s. last 1 is moda1, missing an letter

Comment: That's what I firstly tried too. Inspect the html and you will see why this doesn't work. The id `Dialog1` is inside the modal objects, it does not contain them.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, Is it possible to add reference of different css files for different `modals` using `tag$link()`?